# Exercise taken from a book on the C language

Tags: arrays, c

> A small airline has just purchased a computer for its new automatic
> reservation system. The president has asked you to program the new
> system. Write a schedule to assign seats on each flight of the
> company's only aircraft (10-seat capacity). The program must print the
> following menu of alternatives: 'Please type 1 for first class' and
> 'Please type 2 for economy.'
>
> If the user enters 1, then the program assigns a first-class seat
> (seats 1 to 5). If the user enters 2, then it assigns an economy seat
> (seats 6 to 10).
>
> Use a one-dimensional array by initializing all elements to 0. When
> the first class is full, the program offers the user an economy seat
> (if available); otherwise, it prints 'Next Flight Leaves in 3 hours.'

The program continues to give me problems. If I occupy all the economy seats, the program continues to let me access switch case 2, even though all the seats are occupied. Furthermore, by offering the customer a ticket of another class and accepting it, the program starts again from the beginning and does not switch to the opposite switch case.

I'm not an expert in programming; I'm self-taught from a textbook. Feel free to judge my code even being brutal. I don't want the solution but just to understand where I'm wrong! Thank you all for your time.

```
// TO BE REVIEWED
#include <stdio.h>
#define SEATS 10

int main(void) {
    int flightSeats[SEATS] = {0};
    int userChoice = 0;
    int firstClassSeats = 0;
    int economySeats = 0;
    int continueTravel = 1;
    char changeProposal;

    while (firstClassSeats + economySeats < SEATS && continueTravel) {
        printf("Welcome\nType 1 to travel in First Class\nType 2 to travel in Economy\n");
        scanf("%d", &userChoice);

        switch (userChoice) {
            case 1:
                printf("You have chosen to travel in First Class!\n");
                if (firstClassSeats < 5) {
                    printf("Choose your seat:\n");
                    int chosenSeat;
                    scanf("%d", &chosenSeat);

                    if (chosenSeat >= 1 && chosenSeat <= 5 && flightSeats[chosenSeat - 1] == 0) {
                        flightSeats[chosenSeat - 1]++;
                        printf("Seat no: %d assigned!\n", chosenSeat);
                        firstClassSeats++;
                    } else {
                        printf("Invalid or already occupied seat, please try again!\n");
                    }
                } else if (economySeats < 10) {
                    printf("Sorry, First Class seats are occupied\nDo you want to travel in Economy? (y or n):\n");
                    scanf(" %c", &changeProposal);

                    if (changeProposal == 'y') {
                        userChoice = 2;
                    } else if (changeProposal == 'n') {
                        printf("Thank you and goodbye!\n");
                        continueTravel = 0;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        printf("Please enter a valid character!\n");
                        getchar();
                    }
                } else {
                    printf("Sorry, all seats are occupied!\n");
                    continueTravel = 0;
                    break;
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("You have chosen to travel in Economy!\n");
                if (economySeats < 10) {
                    printf("Choose your seat:\n");
                    int chosenSeat;
                    scanf("%d", &chosenSeat);

                    if (chosenSeat >= 6 && chosenSeat <= 10 && flightSeats[chosenSeat - 1] == 0) {
                        flightSeats[chosenSeat - 1]++;
                        printf("Seat no: %d assigned!\n", chosenSeat);
                        economySeats++;
                    } else {
                        printf("Invalid or already occupied seat, please try again!\n");
                    }
                } else if (firstClassSeats < 5) {
                    printf("Sorry, Economy seats are occupied\nDo you want to travel in First Class? (y or n):\n");
                    scanf(" %c", &changeProposal);

                    if (changeProposal == 'y') {
                        userChoice = 1;
                        
                    } else if (changeProposal == 'n') {
                        printf("Thank you and goodbye!\n");
                        continueTravel = 0;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        printf("Please enter a valid character!\n");
                        getchar();
                    }
                } else {
                    printf("Sorry, all seats are occupied!\n");
                    continueTravel = 0;
                    break;
                }
                break;

            default:
                printf("Please enter a valid number (1 or 2)\n");
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Let me know if my logical idea is correct or if I've misunderstood everything and am getting it all wrong.

I tried adding more checks and various breaks, but I know it's not the cleanest way to solve a problem; I would like to do it properly.

Comment: I suggest you go back to pen and paper on this. Create a flow chart with all possible/expected outcomes and make sure they are all handled. Then start rewriting the code to match. You have some odd logic branches that shouldn't be necessary.  One problem I see right off the bat is that you say there should be 5 economy seats (6-10), but you check in your code if `economySeats < 10`. Why check for 10 seats if you only have 5? Maybe I misunderstand the problem or your intention, but this seems like it has started to run away on you a bit.

Comment: I understand; I'm just struggling with the implementation. In your opinion, do you think my issue lies in making a mistake during the initial planning?

Comment: You are using several magic numbers. One is particularily confusing me, the 10. 10 is the total number of seats (5 first classs, 5 economy) but it looks like you allow to book 10 economy seats. Can you explain? Or alternatively, please provide details on "If I occupy all the economy seats, ..." how does that look? How do you do that? What is the input for doing that?

Comment: @DavideN7 looking at it in an editor, it's not as bad as I initially thought. I think your main mistake lies in checking against the number 10 when checking if more economy seats are available. That would 'fix' the problem you ask about in this question, but there are still some other places you would run into undesired behavior. For instance, in the case you have a full economy, you ask if the user would like first class, but then the loop continues, and you ask again, disregarding the previous choice. It works, but probably not what you want. Some better planning could solve issues like that

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to focus on a specific problem, not just post a bunch of code and ask for general advice.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time :(

Answer (score 2):

I reworked it a bit. Some notes:

- Your main issue preventing it from working as you describe in the question is the use of the number `10` for economy seats.
- I changed the control flow a bit so that it's easier (in my opinion) to follow and reduces a bit of duplication. Mines not perfect either, but hopefully demonstrates a different way of going about things that you may be able to use in the future. Mainly, getting and validating as much as you can up front to avoid having to do the same validations in every case (which gets especially tricky when you need to update magic numbers like `10` in multiple places).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SEATS 10

int main(void){
  int flightSeats[SEATS] = { 0 };
  int userChoice = 0;
  int firstClassSeats = 0;
  int economySeats = 0;
  int continueTravel = 1;
  char changeProposal;

  while (firstClassSeats + economySeats < SEATS && continueTravel){
    printf("Welcome\nType 1 to travel in First Class\nType 2 to travel in Economy\n");
    scanf("%d", &userChoice);

    if (userChoice != 1 && userChoice != 2){
      printf("Invalid choice, please try again!\n");
      continue;
    }

    if ((userChoice == 1 && firstClassSeats == 5) || (userChoice == 2 && economySeats == 5)){
      printf("Sorry, all selected seats are occupied! Choose an alternative?\n");
      scanf(" %c", &changeProposal);
      if (changeProposal == 'y'){
        userChoice = (userChoice == 1) ? 2 : 1;
      } else if (changeProposal == 'n'){
        printf("Thank you and goodbye!\n");
        continueTravel = 0;
        continue;
      } else{
        printf("Invalid character, try again\n");
        continue;
      }
    }

    printf("You have chosen to travel in %s\n", (userChoice == 1) ? "First Class" : "Economy");
    printf("Choose your seat:\n");
    int chosenSeat;
    scanf("%d", &chosenSeat);

    switch (userChoice){
    case 1:
      if (chosenSeat >= 1 && chosenSeat <= 5 && flightSeats[chosenSeat - 1] == 0){
        flightSeats[chosenSeat - 1]++;
        printf("Seat no: %d assigned!\n", chosenSeat);
        firstClassSeats++;
      } else{
        printf("Invalid or already occupied seat, please try again!\n");
      }
      break;

    case 2:
      if (chosenSeat >= 6 && chosenSeat <= 10 && flightSeats[chosenSeat - 1] == 0){
        flightSeats[chosenSeat - 1]++;
        printf("Seat no: %d assigned!\n", chosenSeat);
        economySeats++;
      } else{
        printf("Invalid or already occupied seat, please try again!\n");
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```